# Escape if statement/code block?

Tags: java

Say I have an if block, or any code block for that matter. Is there any good way to escape the rest of the block, like a continue for a loop? I understand goto is defunct in Java.

Example code:

```
if (sid > -1) {
    if (!godDamnDefunctGoto(session, sid)) {
        sid = -1;
    }else {
        vsid = true;
    }
}
```

When I should be able to run my checks here, without calling a method.
The method godDamnDefunctGoto run various checks on my sid & session variable. I don't want to repeat code over and over from returns in the code flow of that method by placing it in this one.

The goal here is to run some code after after that if statement, but not yet return until this has run. I'd have to run it several times if I were to inline the Java method. Perhaps Java should implement the inline keyword, similar to C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the labeled break statement (yes, *break* DOES work without being inside the *while* loop) it is little known in java because it is not a good programming practice (it breaks the [Structured program theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_program_theorem), as it does the *goto* statement)

If you don't believe me, just compile and run this code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean myCondition = false;

        MY_BLOCK: {
            System.out.println("1");
            System.out.println("2");
            System.out.println("3");
            System.out.println("4");

            if(!myCondition) break MY_BLOCK;

            System.out.println("5");
            System.out.println("6");
            System.out.println("7");
        }
        System.out.println("END");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I tried something similar where I did it in front of an if statement, but I did continue, not break. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should write everything inside the if statement as a function, and return when you want to break.

Let's say you the following code, and if a > 23 you want to "break"

```
a = getUserInput();

if (a == 1) {

a = a * 23;
// some other stuff
  if(a > 23){ // you want to "break" if this is true
    System.out.println("break!!");
  }
// Do other stuff

System.out.println(a);
```

You can put the if code in a function:

```
public void processA(Integer a){
  a = a * 23;
  // some other stuff
    if(a > 23){ // you want to "break" if this is true
      return;
    }
  // Do other stuff
}
```

Then, in your code:

```
if (a == 1) {
  processA(a);
}

System.out.println(a);
```

This is how you can do it with a method, there's really no way to break out of an if loop that I can think of otherwise.

If you want to pass several variables to the function, instead of making it take an Integer, make it take a CustomObject, or a "bean" as it's known [(here is a tutorial)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html):

public class CustomObject{
    int intOne;
    int intTwo;
    int intThree;
    // Add getters and setters
}

Comment: This is what you do have to do, but it's ridiculous. In some other cases, I've had 5 or 6 variables I've had to pass to that method.

Comment: OK, see my edit, you make an object containing those variables and pass it instead of a bunch of variables.  Go through the tutorial linked.

Comment: That would be horrible for performance though? Creating an object just to pass variables.

Comment: That's partly what objects are for, did you go through the tutorial?  It's an "official" java tutorial and will give you some ideas for how to do things.  One way to think of an "object" is to think of a related set of properties who as a group are relevant.

Comment: That may be the case, but that doesn't change the facts of poor performance. All I'm trying to do is run some code that can break out of it's self, but instead of I have to make an object, probably slowing the code 2 or 3x over.

Comment: The facts of poor performance?  What facts are those?  Have you timed it, or are you just assuming?  I think you are worrying about the wrong things, to some extent.

Comment: In a high performance requiring environment, this code could be called hundreds of thousands of times per second, creating an object would be detrimental to performance as other scenarios have shown.

Comment: Again, this is very non-specific, and really bordering on nonsense.  If you're that concerned you should be writing it in Assembly.  Java is an Object Oriented language, for pete's sake.

Comment: You should always have some performance in mind, but the code I'm writing especially so.

Comment: @user3618509 If you are really that good, you wouldn't be here asking for help. So, the least you can do is to stop shooting down whatever suggestions people are giving you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do like this

```
    L1: if (C1) {
        P1();
        if (C2)
            break L1;
        P2();
    }
```

You can write like this

```
    while (C1) {
        P1();
        if (C2)
            break;
        P2();
        break;
    }
```